# How can I Filter Segment Conversion Category from Google Ads Source in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-ads-api, looker-studio

I saw a blog where “Segment Conversion Type Name” and “Segment Conversion Category” cannot coexist with non-conversion metrics—such as cost, clicks, or impressions:

https://www.workshopdigital.com/blog/3-google-data-studio-shortcomings-for-ppc-analysts/

I am trying to build us a report that will show the cost per segment conversion category per location but alongside it is I also have the non-conversion metrics. I don't really want to build another table just for the conversions since the data looks messed up.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table report in Google Data Studio and filter by [Segment Conversion Type Name](https://irenoo.com/question/how-can-i-set-up-a-table-showing-the-conversion-action-from-google-ads/):

[image: conversion segment data studio]